# How to Use Bluetooth PAN in 2022?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, bluetooth, tethering

I've been trying to use Bluetooth PAN to share my Macbook's WiFi connection with my phone, since the Macbook has a much better connection range.  However, it seems that Apple removed the built-in ability to use PAN some time ago.

Is there any other way to use Bluetooth PAN on a Mac, be it an app or a port of a Linux hack?

Specs:

- macOS Monterey 12.4
- MacBook Pro (Retina, Early 2015)

Comment: for the moment (12.5)use a different source of the internet or connect the phone via USB. Although this will do the work, a wireless connection is of course more convenient - [this seems to be a bug or Apple removed it from MacOS 12.x](https://piunikaweb.com/2021/12/24/some-macos-12-monterey-users-reporting-missing-bluetooth-pan-option/).